# How to convert object as array Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, select

I have the following query:

```html
$data = DB::table('users')
->select(['id', 'firstName AS inputFirstName', 'lastName AS inputLastName', 'email AS inputEmail'])
->where('id', '=',$id )
->first();
```

It returns object but I need array and I convert it in this way:

```html
$array_data =  json_decode(json_encode((array) $data), true);
```

But I'm not sure this is the right way to do it! I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I need to make this select query with aliases, that's why I'm not using Eloquent but this raw query.

Is there better way to make this select query to return array? Thanks!

Comment: Try casting the object to an array `$array_data = (array)$data;`

Comment: Thanks, it is array now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toArray` method.

You haven an object and you can transform it to and array.

```
$dataArray=$data->toArray();
```

You can find this method in the Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into problems, this will give you a pure PHP solution.

```
foreach($tags as $object) {
  $tag_array[] = $object->name;
}
```